# database normalization (1 to many)

Tags: mysql, xml, database, normalization

I have a collection of xml documents. I need to store the metadta and data from these documents in MySQL database. I have created 3 tables to store the information in db.

1- Documents (docId (pk), docName, plaintext, date, author) 
2- Elements (elementId (pk), docId(fk), elementName, elementValue) 
3- Attributes (attributeId (pk), elementId(fk), attributeName, attributeValue)

what this essentially means is that.. there are many xml documents. each xml document has many elements and each element can have many attributes.. I dont know if i have dont this step properly?? i mean the database normalization.. are these tables in 3rd normal form?

Comment: Something to think about: how does your database schema handle nested XML elements? Or are you sure your documents does not have nested elements?

Comment: @Jan-Henk: hmm... good point..i didn't think of that. i do have nested elements and this explains why i am getting only the last elementId value from Elements table as foreign key value in the attributes table.. and there i was thinking that something's wrong with my db design.. :D ...thanks for pointing this out.. any suggestions??

Comment: solved.Created a list of Elements and a list for Attributes of each element then added them to the elements list:
List elements = new ArrayList();
if(e.isStartElement()){StartElement element = (StartElement)e;
Iterator iterator = element.getAttributes();
List attrs =new ArrayList();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
Attribute attribute=(Attribute)iterator.next();
attrs.add(attribute);
}
elements.add(new Object[]{element,attrs});
}

Then on the other side:
for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++){
Object[] obj=(Object[])elements.get(i);
StartElement element=(StartElement)obj[0];
List attrs=(List)obj[1];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these tables are normalized according to 3NF. There are, in short, three simple rules:

- No repeating elements or groups of elements
- No partial dependencies on concatenated keys
- No functional dependencies on non-key attributes